# Trying to style for 1st <p> element in the div using sass with the same class

Tags: html, css, sass

Below is my code. With that 2nd `<p>` is becoming bold. I just need first `<p>` bold only. I don't want to add any class for 1st `<p>`.

```css
    .person {
      p + p {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="person">
          <p>I am good</p>
          <p>You are also good</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`.person p:first-of-type { }` or even `.person p:first-child { }` would work.  The selector you are using literally translates to "A Paragraph immediately following a Paragraph within class .person"

Comment: I'd use the p:first-of-type selector as well

Answer (score 0):

```
.person {
  p:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
}
```